# Python 2to3 does not change #!/usr/bin/python

Tags: python, python-2to3

I am in the process of converting my python code from 2.7 to 3 using 2to3.  It seems to convert as expected, except that my code always starts with the line `#!/usr/bin/python` which I expected to change to `#!/usr/bin/python3` but it doesn't.  Have I missed something?  Is there a way to get that to happen?

Comment: I think 2to3 is not supposed to do that. It transforms Python code and sees this line as a comment.

Comment: Here is a list of things it does: https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html What you want is not mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

`#!/usr/bin/python` is not a `python` version-dependent statement, or even `python` at all. It essentially instructs a shell to execute the script (file) using the `python` executable (program) located at `/usr/bin`.

The intent behind `2to3` it get you along the path of converting your code to python 3, frequently doing all the work for you. It doesn't address issues outside the `python` code.

It's entirely possible for `/usr/bin/python` to *be* `python` 3. The #! line exists let a shell execute a script using what's typically a systems *default* `python`.